# what configurations should i consider in ekf_localization_node when using IMU and an ultrasonic sensor?

Tags: imu, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good day everyone, now I'm working on a quadcopter project and I'm using IMU(gy-801)  and also an ultrasonic sensor for getting the z-axis ,I have used the accelerometer and the gyroscope data to make the imu_msg and i've visualized this msg using rviz and it works very well then i have put the ultrasonic data and the heading angle in an odometry_msg,then i used this two messages in ekf_localization_node to get the pose and twist but the /odometry_filterd message that is published from that node doesn't give real data and the pose always increases fast although the quadcopter doesn't move. so am i working wrong or is there any configurations that i should consider?? thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298519/what-configurations-should-i-consider-in-ekf_localization_node-when-using-imu-and-an-ultrasonic-sensor??/) by [Mohamed Badra](https://answers.ros.org/users/36637/mohamed-badra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohamed Badra](https://answers.ros.org/users/36637/mohamed-badra/) on 2018-07-25**:
so what sensor do you suggest for a quadcopter odometry?

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-07-25**:
I've seen a lot of people who use visual odometry. If you search google for "ros visual odometry" you'll find lots of examples.

**Comment by [Mohamed Badra](https://answers.ros.org/users/36637/mohamed-badra/) on 2018-07-25**:
thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're feeding noisy acceleration measurements into an EKF without a source of position odometry your position estimate is going to explode. You can do some searching for people who have tried using r_l with just an IMU, but from what I've seen the consensus is that the results won't be great.

---

Originally posted by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) with karma: 929 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0